# Animated children's show from the early 2000's - drink turns you into an alien

Tags: story-identification, tv, animation

I'm trying to remember something from approximately 18 years ago that I saw on cable TV. It was an animated sci-fi story that took place on some kind of spacecraft. The only detail I really recall is that one of the characters drank a can from a vending machine and then morphed into an alien. I was very young when I saw this so I'm pretty sure it what programming made for children. That being said, I've been trying to figure this out for the past decade with no luck, so it's possible that my memory is quite off. I do recall having seen this content on multiple occasions and I don't remember it being part of a series that I watched, so maybe it was just some short that was used to fill time between shows. The most likely networks that I saw this on are Nickelodeon or Cartoon Network.

Comment: What country did you watch it? seeing they also have regional series/shorts and most countries received cartoons years later then the original broadcasting nation(USA).

Comment: Well, if you decided to put a bounty on it, you should try and give us a little more details like: were the characters all human? are there any other spaceships? were the characters from Earth? What did the "alien" looked like?

Comment: @A.bakker It was in the USA

Comment: @RigaCrypto I really wish I had the answer to any of those questions, but I honestly don't remember. I know this is super vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's an episode of The Cartoon Cartoon Show: "[King Crab: Space Crustacean](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1392178/)" in which the captain's sidekick finds a vending machine in an abandoned ship with a parasite that fuses with him into an alien species.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You could improve this answer if you can find the specific episode you're referring to.

Comment: AHHHHHHH! THIS IS ACTUALLY IT! Unbelievable. Thank you so much!

Comment: @DavidW I haven't seen it myself, but I believe that King Crab: Space Crustacean only had a single episode - it was a pilot, which was not picked up to become a series.

Answer (score 5):

Tv show Alienators: Evolution Continues (Known as Evolution: the Animated Series in some regions including the United Kingdom) could fit the bill.

It is animated comic sci-fi television series based on the 2001 film Evolution.

Original release dates:September 15, 2001 –June 22, 2002

More details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alienators:_Evolution_Continues).

Why it might fit:

> Teenage "wannabe fireman" Wayne Grey (who's been renamed Wayne Green)
>   – A 17-year-old firefighter-in-training. Being the first human
>   infected with alien DNA, he develops a "sympathetic mutation", causing
>   him to mutate parallel to any Genus strains encountered.

He changes into new "alien" every episode.

Here is intro, see if it looks familiar.

Comment: This might be it. I'm gonna have to scroll through a couple episodes to see if I can find my specific memory.

Comment: The episode "Don't Drink The Water" is likely what I'm remembering. It doesn't look right, but enough of the pieces are in place that I can reasonably play this up to a memory that morphed over time. Thank you for the closure on this.

Comment: Turns out this wasn't it. The answer below is actually what I was remembering.

Comment: Ok. I'm glad you found it.